# repaint not working when button is pushed

Tags: java, user-interface, applet, repaint

I am trying to get my code to work such that when you push the "Go!" button, it either draws a hand of cards or shuffles the deck, depending on the checkbox selected. I think I can figure that out later, but the problem right now is that when I push the "Go!" button, nothing happens; it doesn't draw a box or write using g.drawString().

The code happens in sequence, meaning you're shown a textbox field and a button, which, when pressed, clears the screen then brings up the "Go!" button and the checkboxes. But nothing happens when go is pushed.

Thanks for any help you can provide, it is very much appreciated, and here's the code (in all of its messy, unfinished glory):

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class cardGame extends Applet implements ActionListener{

TextField nameField;
Button nameOk;
Button go;
Label title;
CheckboxGroup options;
Checkbox shuffle;
Checkbox deal;
Random rand;
Random rand2;

int[] deck;

public void init(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    menuFont = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,25);

    nameField = new TextField("Type Name Here",35);
    nameOk = new Button("Enter");
    shuffle = new Checkbox("Shuffle Deck",options,false);
    deal = new Checkbox("Deal",options,false);
    go = new Button("Go!");
    title = new Label("Welcome to the Card Table", Label.CENTER);
    rand = new Random();
    rand2 = new Random();

    deck = new int[] {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13};

    add(nameField);
    add(nameOk);
    add(title);

    nameOk.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    if(evt.getSource() == nameOk){
        clearAll();
        newOptions();
    }
    if(evt.getSource() == go){
        //if(deal.getState()==true&&shuffle.getState()==true)System.out.println("Only one, please");
        if(shuffle.getState()){
        shuffleDeck(deck);
    }
        clearAll();
        repaint();
    }
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    /*if(shuffle.getState()){
        shuffleDeck(deck);
    }*/
    if(deal.getState())g.drawRect(100,100,100,100);
    //if(deal.getState()==true&&shuffle.getState()==true)g.drawString("Only one, please",100,100);
}
public void clearAll(){
    remove(nameField);
    remove(nameOk);
    remove(title);
    remove(go);
    remove(shuffle);
    remove(deal);
    revalidate();
}
public void newOptions(){
    //Dimension d = getSize();
    add(shuffle);
    add(deal);
    add(go);
    revalidate();
}
public void shuffleDeck(int[] nums){
    //int a=0,count2=0,count3=0,count4=0,count5=0,count6=0,count7=0,count8=0,count9=0,count10=0,countJ=0,countQ=0,countK=0;
    int n;
    int n2;
    int temp;
    for(int i = 52;i>0;i--){
        n=rand.nextInt(52);
        n2=rand2.nextInt(52);
        temp=nums[n];
        nums[n]=nums[n2];
        nums[n2]=temp;
    }
}
public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);
}
public void stop(){

}
```

}

Comment: Becareful with overriding `paint`.  Not calling `super.paint` could prevent it from rendering any of the child components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not attached any `ActionListener` to the `go` button...

Try adding `go.addActionListener(this);` after `nameOk.addActionListener(this);`